# How is resource utilization calculated?

Tags: anylogic

How is the utilization of a resource calculated?

I have a resource pool with only one resource available. When the resource is sized, the utilization begins to increase and in an arbitrary moment of time while doing its first task it reaches 99%. Then, when the resource is released the utilization begins to decrease slowly.

I suppose utilization is measured respect to time, but how is the equation Anylogic uses? What does it mean a utilization of 50% while the resource is doing his task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AnyLogic is using the following formula for resource utilization U = (total time seized) / (total time available from beginning of the model excluding maintenance).

So, for example,  if model is at time 10, and unit was seized from 0-5 then utilization will be 50% and then at time 20 the utilization will be 25%. You can find more information in 'Utilization Statistics' section [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/resource-api.html?resultof=%22%72%65%73%6f%75%72%63%65%75%6e%69%74%22%20).