# Utilization of a Resource

Tags: anylogic

Is there any way to calculate the utilization of a given resource in a specific time frame? I have a machine that works h24, but during daytime hours its utilization is higher than during nighttime hours.
In the final statistics, using the function "machine.utilization()" I get a low result, which is influenced by the night hours. How can I split the two statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilization is calculated as (work time)/(available time excluding maintenance). Which means that the measure described in your question can be achieved using 2 ways:

1. Make the machine 'unavailable' during the night, this way that time will be excluded in calculations
2. **ResourcePool** object has 2 properties `on resource seize` and `on resource release` which can be used to record specific instances of work time, sum it up and divide only by a period of (8hr * (num of days)) instead of total time from model start

For a little more detail and link to AnyLogic help please see the answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088595/1799849).

**Update**:
In **ResourcePool**'s `On seize` and `On release`, AnyLogic provides a parameter called *unit*, which is the specific resource unit agent being processed. So getting actual use time per unit requires following:

1. 2 collections of type LinkedHashMap that maps Agent -> Double. One collection to store start times (let's call it `col_start` and one to store total use times, let's call it `col_worked`)
2. `On seize` should contain this code: `col_start.put(unit, time())`
3. `On release` should contain:

```java
double updated = col_worked.getOrDefault(unit, 0.0) + (time() - col_start.get(unit));
col_worked.put(unit, updated);
```

This way at any given point during model execution, `col_worked` will contain a mapping of resource unit Agent to the total sum of time it was utilised expressed as a double value in model time units.

Comment: how can i register specific instances? if i create local variables in the on seize , it does not read them in the release. If I create absolute variables, they will be used by all resources and I will not be able to count them.