# Time Distribution and time spent in process in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on production model where the the input of raw material is on hourly bases and i am running the model for 8 hours ( 1 shift ) so basically for 16 hour the resources are idle. When i was not using the schedule part and running the model for 8 *7 hours ( 56 hours) then the time measurement for each job is fine but now when i schedule the output it include the idle time also. So How can i only calculate the busy time to see the average time spent by a job in a workshop ( from raw material to finish good.

[This the time spent by a job in a process it should be 34-16= approx 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXM78.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Utilization of a Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600067/utilization-of-a-resource)

Comment: No, actually I am running a shift of 8 hours from morning 8 PM to 6PM, I am trying to calculate the TAT for that service block. Now what happing is for agent which arrives in service block at 5:45PM complete it task in next moring at 8:45AM and total time spent increase to 17 hour. System is consider the waiting hour too. I want to rest the starting time of such agents, so that my TAT wont get affected.

Comment: So to clarify: in the example of agent arriving at 17:45 and exiting at 8:45 you want it to record 1 hr instead of 17 hrs?

Comment: Yes, Basically start time should change with scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, one note: although you state that you run 8 hour shifts, the 8 AM to 6 PM time period is actually 10 hours so I will ignore it in this solution and instead assume that the shifts are actually 8 hours and run from 9:00 to 17:00.

Here is a simple model that was used to test (model time unit is SECONDS):

[image]

There are 4 elements to make this work:

1. **Service** must be configure to allow pre-emption of tasks with recovery this is done by using *Priorities / preemption* options as below:

[image]

2. **ResourcePool** must be configure for 'End of Shift' preemption as shown below:

[image]

3. Calculations of true time (excluding dead time between shifts) is done in `f_calcTATsec` function:

```java
// get 'Service' enter time for that agent
double startTime = col_startTimesSec.get(_agent);

// calculate time spent
double timeSpent = time() - startTime;

traceln("%.2f: agent spent %.2f in service", time(), timeSpent);
traceln("%.2f: 8hrs is %.2f, 16hrs is %.2f", 
    time(), (8 * hour()), (16 * hour()));

// below is a ternary statement which says:
//   if 'timeSpent' is less than 8 hrs then use it
//   otherwise 
//      exclude whole 16 hr periods (can be more than 1) 
//      and use the remainder
double trueTimeSpent = timeSpent <= (8 * hour()) ? 
    timeSpent :
    timeSpent % (16 * hour());

// return time spent
traceln("%.2f: returning %.2f", time(), trueTimeSpent);
return trueTimeSpent;
```

4. **Service** object needs to be configured to record entry time for each Agent in *col_startTimeSec* collection and then call `f_calcTATsec()` function on exit, i.e. **On enter** = `col_startTimesSec.put(agent, time());` and **On exit** = `double trueTimeSpentSec = f_calcTATsec(agent);`

Comment: This is overcomplicated (the Service block actions already help you distinguish moments when pre-empted tasks are suspended and resumed) and --- if doing it like this --- would be more robust if it used the schedule objects to calculate what the duration was between the last shift-end to the shift-start. Also, I suspect the OP actually wants to track waiting time in general (not just during pre-emption wait-for-original-resource) because this makes little sense as a metric as-is.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, yes, I agree adding a variable to the job agent and tracking it with **On task suspended / resumed** is more robust long term if the OP wants to have variable shift length and no work on weekends.

Answer (score 1):

> When i was not using the schedule part and running the model for 8 *7 hours ( 56 hours) then the time measurement for each job is fine but now when i schedule the output it include the idle time also

So I assume you were using TimeMeasureStart/End blocks to do the time-in-system measurement. They just calculate the elapsed time from the start block to the end block, and so can never account for 'time that shouldn't count'. You don't have to use these blocks to calculate timings; typically you store relevant start times in the (custom) agent type flowing through the process and then calculate the relevant elapsed times as needed (e.g., at on-exit of a Service block, pseudo-code is "current time - time-on-entry = elapsed time in block").

Firstly though, you need to be clearer about what metric you're calculating and why. You want to exclude time where an in-progress (presumably pre-empted) job waits for the resource to return on-shift. But what about jobs which are *queueing* for a resource which then goes off-shift? What about if there are multiple possible resources that can be used with different shift patterns? What about the more general waiting of jobs for resources (when resources are on-shift)?

It sounds like what you may really want is both

- The elapsed time spent *working* on a job (cf. waiting for anything).
- The elapsed time jobs spend *waiting* for something (typically resources in a Seize/Service block — not just when tasks are pre-empted by shift-end — but could be other wait mechanisms, such as using Wait blocks).

The latter is just the total elapsed time minus the former.

So there are multiple ways to tackle this. Probably the easiest is to retain your overall elapsed time (via TimeMeasureStart/End blocks) and then calculate the working time separately: store it as a variable in the job agent and add to it in each block where it has 'work done to it' (e.g., for Service blocks without pre-emption use duration from on-seize to on-exit, for Delay blocks use duration from on-enter to on-exit).

To handle where a shift-end-pre-empted task waits for a resource to return on-shift you can use the Service block's "On task suspended" and "On task resumed" actions which trigger when a task is suspended (due to pre-emption) or resumed (when the original resource becomes available if that's the preemption option you chose).

This requires an extra variable to store the "current duration start time".

To be explicit:

- Type `double` Variable `cumulativeWorkingTimeMins` in your Job agent type
- Type `double` Vriable `currentWorkStartTimeMins` in your Job agent type

...and for a Service block (handling the pre-emption case)

- 'On seize unit' (or 'On enter delay') action of `agent.currentWorkStartTimeMins = time(MINUTE);`
- 'On task suspended' action of `agent.cumulativeWorkingTimeMins += (time(MINUTE) - agent.currentWorkStartTimeMins);`
- 'On task resumed' action of `agent.currentWorkStartTimeMins = time(MINUTE);`
- 'On exit' action of `agent.cumulativeWorkingTimeMins += (time(MINUTE) - agent.currentWorkStartTimeMins);`

[Note units specified in variable names to be clear, and explicit specification of units when getting the current time; this ensures the code is robust to changing your model time unit.]

**NB**: If you *really* wanted to just subtract the time pre-empted jobs are waiting for off-shift resources to return (and no other waiting time) — which doesn't seem to make sense as a metric — you can still do that using a variant of the above which just captures that waiting time.

(You'll also need to store the relevant final numbers in some `HistogramData` element or similar when the job finishes to be able to then show this data in charts: the `TimeMeasureEnd` blocks automatically capture this histogram data in their `distribution` variable but, when calculating timings yourself, you need to store data yourself for charts.)